# Find header in VBA

Tags: vba, excel, header

I have a function in VBA that finds headers and selects the column below the header.  It works beautifully except for one instance where I am trying to find a column with CLIENT as the header and it keeps selecting the column with "CLIENT ID as the header (which is right next to it).  I was trying to put something in the function to handle this but everytime I try to, it just fails.  Any help with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

```
Function FindHeader(HEADER_NAME As String, sheetName As String) As Range

    Dim rngHeaders As Range
    Dim rngHdrFound As Range

    Const ROW_HEADERS As Integer = 1

    Set rngHeaders = Intersect(Worksheets(sheetName).UsedRange, Worksheets(sheetName).Rows(ROW_HEADERS))
    Set rngHdrFound = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME)

    If rngHdrFound Is Nothing Then
       MsgBox ("ERROR: Cannot find appropriate header.")
        Exit Function
    ElseIf rngHdrFound = "CLIENT" Then
     'Handle Client range here   
    End If

  Set FindHeader = Range(rngHdrFound.Offset(1), rngHdrFound.End(xlDown))

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

Change the FIND method to find only an entire, and not a partial, match. Just make sure that this doesn't have negative consequences elsewhere.

```
Set rngHdrFound = rngHeaders.Find(HEADER_NAME,,,xlWhole)
```